# html 5 parsing media queries vs html 4.0 transitional

Tags: html, parsing, css, media-queries, doctype

Im compiling some static html documents from some Handelbar templates. I mistakenly forgot the `html` in `<!doctype html>` which made my document interpreted a little different, im assuming 4.0 transitional... thats what w3c says.

So I added it in and now some of my `@media` queries in my css are not being read. I haven't changed css files at all.

If I remove the `html` from the doctype they work again. I think it might have to do with the encoding which I set to `utf-8` and it looks like it defaults to `utf-8`.

my media queries look like

```
@media all and (max-width : 480px){
  /* this is not applied */
}
```

weird thing is that I have Zurb foundation installed and it's queries work fine eg.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px){
  /*eh this works in zurb*/
}
```

Im also using SCSS to compile my CSS.

Comment: Do you mean you had the HTML4 transitional DOCTYPE instead of the HTML5 one, or that you had no DOCTYPE?

Comment: I had `<!doctype >` so no doctype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The css file was being compiled up a different way the `utf-8` via SCSS, so the encoding was wrong. Before I there was no strict encoding because the `html` missing in the `doctype` was throwing an error making the html parsing bypass my `meta charset` being set.

So all I did was in my SCSS file i specified

`@charset "utf-8";`

and now I'm compliant to standards and my media queries are working yeee